# PowerShell script to rename files printed by a precise printer

Tags: powershell, printing

I want to make a script that automatically rename a PDF file when I print it on a certain Printer.
But my script doesn't seem to work as planned, here it is:

```
# Set up the printer to monitor
$printer_name = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
# Set up a loop to continuously monitor the printer
while ($true) {
    # Get the list of print jobs for the printer
    $print_jobs = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PrintJob -Filter "Name = '$printer_name'"
    Write-Output $print_job
    # Check if there are any print jobs for the printer
    if ($print_jobs) {
        # Get the first print job in the list
        $print_job = $print_jobs[0]

        # Check if the print job is complete
        if ($print_job.Status -eq "Printed") {
            
            # Print a message in the terminal
            Write-Output "Print detected!"
            # Get the file path of the printed PDF
            $pdf_path = $print_job.Document
            # Build the new file name
            $new_name = "$($pdf_path.Substring(0, $pdf_path.LastIndexOf('.'))) - Printed.pdf"
            # Rename the file
            Rename-Item -Path $pdf_path -NewName $new_name
        }
    }

}
```

I tried to do a step by step method:

renaming a file:

```
# Set the path to the PDF file
$pdf_path = "C:\path\to\test.pdf"

# Build the new file name
$new_name = "$($pdf_path.Substring(0, $pdf_path.LastIndexOf('.'))) - Printed.pdf"

# Rename the file
Rename-Item -Path $pdf_path -NewName $new_name
```

detecting a printer when used:

```
# Set up a loop to continuously monitor printers
while ($true) {
    # Get the list of print jobs for all printers
    $print_jobs = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PrintJob

    # Check if there are any print jobs for any printer
    if ($print_jobs) {
        # Iterate over the list of print jobs
        foreach ($print_job in $print_jobs) {
            # Get the name of the printer
            $printer_name = $print_job.Name
            # Print a message in the PowerShell window
            Write-Output "Print detected on printer $printer_name!"
        }
    }
}
```

My result for printing a PDF using the printer "Microsoft Print to PDF" :
Print detected on printer Microsoft Print to PDF, 22!
If I print once again:
Print detected on printer Microsoft Print to PDF, 23!

It seems like the printer name is incrementing each time I print, so i might have missunderstood something...

How can I get the right Printer name ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Name` of each print job is composed of the printer name + the job id. Remove the trailing ID before outputting:

```
Write-Output "Print detected on printer $($printer_name -replace ', \d+\s*$')!"
```